# Putting CSV Data as is into a New CSV

Tags: csv, powershell, import

I have a CSV file with two columns; Identitiy, and User. the User column contains UserPrincipalNames, and the Identity column contains a name. What I'm trying to do is to take the Userprincipalnames and get the Displayname from them, which I am able to do.

What I can't figure out it how to get each rows Identity (which is already in the csv I imported) to be displayed alongside the newly found Displayname. I'm not using the Identity column to get anything, I just want to display the values again.

The code I'm using is this:

```
$accounts = ipcsv 'D:\code-folder\small-results.csv'

$accounts | % {
$Identity = $_.Identity
$User = $_.User
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $User | select Displayname
}
```

This gets the `displayname`, but nothing more. I tried placing the `$Identity` variable in the select, but that didn't work. I feel like there must be a simple solution to this.

For example,a row in the CSV file would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50fvT.png)

But I want the output to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjclD.png), but the output I'm getting leaves out the Identity, and I don't know how to have it added.

Comment: can you provide one example record and the desired output?

Comment: Added example and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom column with `Select-Object` (`select`):

```
$accounts = ipcsv 'D:\code-folder\small-results.csv'

$accounts | % {
    $Identity = $_.Identity
    $User = $_.User
    Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $User | select @{n='Identity';e={$Identity}},Displayname
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it says that the term 'Identity' is not recognized in the n=Identity portion.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new `PSCustomObject`for each row and pipe the result to `Export-Csv`:

```
$accounts = ipcsv 'D:\code-folder\small-results.csv'

$accounts | % {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
        Identity = $_.Identity
        User = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.User | select Displayname
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\code-folder\small-results.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```